# How to create MPEG-DASH manifest with multiple fallback URL?

Tags: cdn, mpeg-dash, mpd

I have a URL like this http://.../test/index.mpd. What I want is create another dash manifest that will contain multiple fallback URLs pointing the original manifest file.

For example for URL http://example.com/test/index.mpd (original manifest), the new manifest file should contain multiple CDN URLs like:

```
http://cdn1.com/example/test/index.mpd
http://cdn2.com/example/test/index.mpd
http://cdn3.com/example/test/index.mpd
```

I found something similar in following URL https://bitmovin.com/docs/player/faqs/how-can-i-utilize-the-cdn-fallback-feature-of-the-player. However, this example adds base URLs to the original manifest file and It does not work for dynamic manifest(live stream). Is there any way to do that. I cannot find good documentation or examples on dash manifest manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is via BaseURLs. What do you mean by "It does not work for dynamic manifest"? BaseURLs work independently of the manifest type and definitely do work in dynamic manifests. Perhaps your player is at fault?

Another option is to specify the alternative MPD URLs in `<Location>` tags which allows you to specify multiple locations at which the MPD is available, but IMO BaseURL is better specified for CDN failover.

Comment: Hello. There is a live stream manifest generated by flussonic. Instead of manipulating the original file, I copied the file and added baseURL. In theory no matter where I put this file since baseURL points to correct segment location that player should play the stream. This works with DVR manifest. DVR manifest is static and all the segments are visible in the manifest file. However, in live stream manifest (which is dynamic) there are only 4 segments and as the file is constantly changing, the segments change as well.

Comment: At this moment, the copy and the original files do not have the same segments and when you try to play copy manifest file, it throws an error related with segments. Is there a way to create a separate mpd file without segments but just a couple of baseURLs  pointing to original manifest file.

Comment: No, this isn't possible within the DASH specification. Typically, what you describe is solved using higher level application logic to detect errors thrown by the player then reload an alternative manifest from a different URL, provided by some other means, and seek to the correct place.